# Add Wiki Page Library pages (not the publishing wiki) with PowerShell CSOM SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Made a Wiki Page Library (not the publishing wiki) and can add pages with content like below, but when the page renders there is no SharePoint Chrome, just my content shows up. here is code. I it seems there may be one more property to add so master page takes effect?

```
$FileCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation 
        $FileCreationInformation.Url = $FileRef
        $FileCreationInformation.Overwrite = $true
        $FileCreationInformation.Content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($HTMLPageContent) 
        $wikiFile = $WikiPageList.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInformation)
        $ClientContext.Load($wikiFile)  
        $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to create a page in Wiki Page Library using CSOM in SharePoint 2013

Use [Utility.CreateWikiPageInContextWeb method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.createwikipageincontextweb(v=office.15).aspx) to create a page in `Wiki Page Library`:

```
Function Create-WikiPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[string]$WikiLibraryTitle,[string]$PageName,[string]$PageContent)
{
    $wikiLibrary = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($wikiLibraryTitle)
    $Context.Load($wikiLibrary.RootFolder)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $wikiPageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.WikiPageCreationInformation
    $wikiPageInfo.WikiHtmlContent = $PageContent
    $wikiPageInfo.ServerRelativeUrl = [String]::Format("{0}/{1}", $wikiLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, $PageName)
    $wikiFile = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility]::CreateWikiPageInContextWeb($Context, $wikiPageInfo)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()   
}
```

**Usage**

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
Create-WikiPage -Context $Context -WikiLibraryTitle "KBList" -PageName "Welcome.aspx" -PageContent "Welcome to the SharePoint!"
$context.Dispose()
```

Comment: Vadim you are a legend. Thank you. This code will throw a message `New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.` if the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll are not loaded using `Add-Type`