# Sharepoint: which dll holds Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a wiki page to a Sharepoint online/365 site. For this, I need to be able to

```
$wikiFile = $wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add($targetPath, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
```

Which is code I've seen in other peoples snippets and seems to work for them because they do

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
```

at the beginning of their code. Unfortunately the above doesn't do anything for me,

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded
```

probably because I don't have the client side SDK installed (and no admin rights on my work computer to do so). I've gotten as far as I've gotten by using the MICROSOFT.SHAREPOINT.CLIENT.DLL which I've extracted from the SDK installation file and loaded by doing

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$scriptdir\dll\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
```

So now I'm hoping there's some additional dll which I need to load which will then give me access to Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType... I've tried loading all other DLLs from that SDK installation file, but that doesn't remove the error. Anybody know which DLL file to use? And a download link would be appreciated of course.

Comment: Turns out this can be avoided by using the code from
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789829/add-wiki-page-library-pages-not-the-publishing-wiki-with-powershell-csom-share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the information from [this project](https://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/) and combining it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789829/add-wiki-page-library-pages-not-the-publishing-wiki-with-powershell-csom-share), I've put together the following code to send contents to SharePoint O365 from a client computer (make sure to change the paths when you use this code!):

```
# global vars
$clientContext
$rootSiteUrl

#the $PSScriptRoot variable changes over time so let's stick the value to our own variable
$scriptdir = $PSScriptRoot

function Initialize-SPPS
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$siteURL,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [bool]$online,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
        [string]$username,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
        [string]$password
    )
    Write-Host "Loading the CSOM library" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$scriptdir\dll\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
    Write-Host "Succesfully loaded the CSOM library" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green

    Write-Host "Create client context for site $siteUrl" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)

    $context.RequestTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;

    if ($online)
    {
        Write-Host "Setting SharePoint Online credentials" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow

        $context.AuthenticationMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode]::Default
        $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

        $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
        $context.Credentials = $credentials
    }

    Write-Host "Check connection" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
    $web = $context.Web
    $site = $context.Site
    $context.Load($web)
    $context.Load($site)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    Set-Variable -Name "clientContext" -Value $context -Scope Global
    Set-Variable -Name "rootSiteUrl" -Value $siteURL -Scope Global

    Write-Host "Succesfully connected" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green
}
# get files for variables
    # get file for pagename
    $pageName = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\workspace\PortableSoft\UniServerZ\www\wikimigration\powershell\pageName.txt")
    # get file for page contents
    $pageContent = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\workspace\PortableSoft\UniServerZ\www\wikimigration\powershell\pageContent.txt")

# connect
Initialize-SPPS -siteURL "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/123456/" -online $true -username "user@xxx.com" -password "myPass" 

# put page
$fullPageName = "$pageName.aspx"
Write-Host "Adding page" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
Create-WikiPage -Context $clientContext -WikiLibraryTitle "Site Pages" -PageName $fullPageName -PageContent $pageContent
Write-Host "New page added" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green

$clientContext.Dispose()
```

The Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll you can get from the [SharePoint SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30722). If, like me, you're working for a company with strict user privileges, you won't be allowed to actually install it: just use 7zip or something to open the downloaded file as if it were a zipped file and extract the dll that way.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work, because the "Add" method you're using isn't the one that takes two arguments. This is the Files.Add, which takes only the one argument, while the one you think you're using is SPFileCollection.Add.

No idea how to make the code so you use the second one while not being on the actual server though.